# In SQLAlchemy are the ForeignKey and foreign_keys attribute of a relationship linked?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Assuming we have two models:

```
class Store(Base):
    __table_name__ = 'store'
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    location = Column(Text, nullable=True)

class Client(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'client'

    store_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Store.id), primary_key=True)
    payment_completed = Column(Boolean)

    store = relationship('Store', foreign_keys='Client.store_id')
```

if I create a client instance and then change the store property like so:

```
store_1=Store(name='store_1')
client = Client(store_id=store_1.id)
store_2=Store(name='store_2')
client.store = store_2
```

will the `client.store_id` property also be updated? If yes how does `SQLAlchemy` does this automatically behind the scenes?